# Django Multiple Databases Set Up

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, django-database

I am trying to configure my django site to utilise two databases. My site is deployed via Heroku and I have a 'follower' database which is a read-only copy of my main database. As per my understanding from the Heroku docs, any changes to my main database are streamed live to the follower database.

So what I am trying to achieve is making all read operations go to the follower database and write operations to hit the main database.

Any help would be amazing.

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Hi,

I have seen that link and tried to implement it but can't seem to make it point to the other database.

Comment: You have to specify the DB you want to save to if it's not the default one ... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save